# How to add serial numbers to menu items in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu

I use [this wordpress class](https://github.com/roikles/Wordpress-Bem-Menu/) to customize menu in BEM methodology. But I need to add to each first level menu item the class with consecutive numbers. For the first item it should be `.main-nav__item_order_1`, for second `.main-nav__item_order_2` and so on. Does anyone have any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this: https://gist.github.com/podlebar/6da77f557a207e4c675c

i changed code on line 6, 56 and 76

what i did:
added a new variable counter.. apply it if menu element is first level.. if depth is 0 i increase the counter so on the next parent it will be one more.. without the check on line 76 it will increase with every element

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works fine. Unfortunately I can't give like to you answer :(